# How to setup mplabx UART console for ATxmega192A3

Tags: c, debugging, uart, mplab-x

Instructions for setting up UART console output in mplabx:
https://microchipdeveloper.com/xwiki/bin/view/software-tools/xc8/simulator-console/

Says to set select **Uart1 IO Options** to enable output, but there is no **Uart1 IO Options**. I guess not applicable to ATxmega192A3.

There are several UART options and I enabled all of them, but I don't get any output. Well, I don't expect output since I need to implement putch. I added a simple version of putch and put a breakpoint in it, but it's never called. So, clearly it's not configured right.

```
void putch(unsigned char data)
{
    char buffer[16];
    sprintf(buffer, "%c", data);
}
```

Is it possible to setup UART console output for this device? If so how? And further, what would putch look like?